# How to validate Kashruth of an old Shofar?

Tags: hechsher-certification, shofar

I have an old Shofar.  When I say old, I don't mean a family heirloom or antique - I bought it on a family trip to Israel in the early 1990s.  There have been some articles recently discussing the growing market for "biblical ram's horns" among a growing demographic of Christians interested in exploring Judaism (generally as a means of enriching their Christian beliefs, not intending to convert to Judaism).  It seems that there is growing concern, and perhaps even some evidence, that Shofar producers are selling Shofaroth with very well disguised defects that render them not Kosher.

Since I bought my Shofar from a Judaica store in the Old City of Jerusalem, I have always assumed it was Kosher.  I have no recollection of whether or not it was marked with a Hechsher, if such Hechsherim existed at the time, nor would I have been able to tell at that time if such a marking was, in fact, reliable.  I am reading now that some Hechsherim today, obscure though they are, in fact only validate that the Shofar came from an animal whose horns are valid for making a Shofar, but not that the product itself, after manufacture, is Kosher.

How can I validate the Kashruth of my Shofar?

Comment: Does it have any unexpected holes or cracks, or foreign materials (glues, plastics)?

Comment: @DoubleAA, no. But from what I'm reading, they are very difficult to detect to the naked eye.

Comment: @DoubleAA, it has a decorative etching, but that's it.

Comment: Very related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2347/shofar-certification/