# Is there a easy way to determine if a Shofar is Kosher?

Tags: halacha, rosh-hashanah-new-year, shofar

From the following article at [Hasofer.com](http://www.hasofer.com/page.pl?p=kosher-shofar) it seems like the only way to be certain that one has a Kosher Shofar is by buying one with a Hechsher.

> The only way you can be sure that you are buying a kosher shofar is if
>   it has a hechsher, certification certificate, physically attached to
>   it, normally an adhesive sticker.

Is this accurate? Is there a way of determining whether a Shofar is Kosher even without certification?

Comment: See also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2347